# How can I use php composer on linux hosting

Tags: php, pdf, composer-php

I have linux hosting to code with php. I am developing sample php page and I want to convert it to pdf file.

When I do some research, I come across 'composer require dompdf/dompdf' style usage methods.

However, I don't know how to use composer in linux hosting, how to install this plugin there. I would be very happy if you could help with this.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-linux-unix-macos

Comment: It’s the same answer irrespective of the os

Comment: How do you deploy (install) your PHP application without Composer normally? Linux hosting generally is fine (and I personally find it preferable for PHP apps), Composer does not make much of a difference there. However you don't use Composer on the server (hosting), but when preparing the application revision for deployment (build). So it normally does not run on linux hosting, but on the (linux in your case?) build/development box.

Answer (score 0):

This just means that dompdf is not installed on the server you can either use composer to install it and have it autoload or you can manually install dompdf and require the files.

In order to do this you need to first install composer onto the server, see

```
https://getcomposer.org/download/
```

Once you have composer installed you need to create a composer.json file (look online for examples) and inside the composer.json file you need to add dompdf within the require section.

Once thats done you need to run "composer install" on the server to install dompdf.

Heres a sample composer.json file i have for one of my projects this can vary based on what framework (if any) your using:

```
    {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "dompdf/dompdf": "^1.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.65",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php" : "3.222.16"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Http/Helpers.php" 
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```